# Determine the vectors of components

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

For the polynomial vector space $\mathbb{R}[x]$ of degree $\leq 3$ we have the following three bases: 
$$B_1 = \{1 - X^2 + X^3, X - X^2, 1 - X + X^2, 1 - X\} , \\ 
B_2 = \{1 - X^3, 1 - X^2, 1 - X, 1 + X^2 - X^3\}, \\ 
B_3 = \{1, X, X^2, X^3\}$$

How can we determine the following vectors of components $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

$\Theta_{B_1}(b)$ for all $b \in B_1$

and

$\Theta_{B_3}(b)$ for all $b \in B_1$

Could you give me  hint?

Do we use the transformation matrix? If yes, how?

$$$$

**EDIT**:

I have seen the following notes :

$\Theta_{B_1}(b\in B_1)=i$-th comlumn of idenity, since it shown always at itself, and $\Theta_{B_3}(b\in B_1)=i$-th column of $B_1$.

Why does this hold?

Comment: I'll take a look tomorrow

Comment: Your question never seems to reference $B_2$. Is the question copied correctly?

Comment: Normally, there are also other cases for $\Theta$. @robjohn

Comment: What exactly *is* $\Theta$? I was assuming that it was the component vector with respect to a particular basis.

Comment: Yes, it is that... So, $\Theta_{B_1}(b)$ for $b\in B_1$ is the $\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&-1&1\\
0&1&-1&0\\
1&-1&1&0\\
1&-1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$ right? But what is $\Theta_{b_3}(b)$ for $b\in B_1$ ? @robjohn

Comment: Does $\Theta_{B_1}(b)$ maybe mean the multiplication of $\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&-1&1\\ 0&1&-1&0\\ 1&-1&1&0\\ 1&-1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$ and all the $b$ of $B_1$ ? @robjohn

Comment: I have seen the following notes (but I don't know if they are correct) : 
$\Theta_{B_1}(b\in B_1)=i$-th comlumn of idenity, since it shown always at itself, $\Theta_{B_3}(b\in B_1)=i$-th column of $B_1$. Why does this hold? @robjohn

Comment: It depends on what basis $b$ is given in. $B_3$ is what I usually think of as the "standard" basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
B_1=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&X&X^2&X^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&1&1\\
0&1&-1&-1\\
-1&-1&1&0\\
1&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B_2=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&X&X^2&X^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
0&0&-1&0\\
0&-1&0&1\\
-1&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B_3=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&X&X^2&X^3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note that the columns of the matrices above are the matrices for the various bases with respect to $B_3$.

---

For example, consider the first vector of $B_1$, $1-X^2+X^3$
$$
\Theta_{B_3}\!\left(1-X^2+X^3\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
since
$$
1-X^2+X^3=
\overbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
1&X&X^2&X^3
\end{bmatrix}}^{B_3}
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\-1\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This is how the matrix for $B_1$ was created.

Comment: To find the first one do we have to multply all the elements of the basis $B_1$ by $B_1$ ?

Comment: Or which is the method to ifnd the vectors of components?

Comment: The vector $b$ is going to be given with respect to some basis. I usually think of $B_3$ as a "standard" basis. Using the matrix equations above, we can convert from one basis to another.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: Do you maybe have also an idea for my other question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2052517/which-is-the-extended-basis ?