# Which is the extended basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $t\in \mathbb{R}$  and the vectors \begin{equation*}v_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1\\ 
-1\\ 
t
\end{pmatrix}, v_2=\begin{pmatrix}
t\\ 
2\\ 
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}, v_3=\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
2\\ 
2\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*} in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

We have the following: 
\begin{align*}&\begin{pmatrix}
0 & t & 2 \\ 
1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
-1 & 0 & 2 \\ 
t & 1 & 0  
\end{pmatrix}\rightarrow\ldots \rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 \\ 
0 & 0 & t-1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0   
\end{pmatrix}\end{align*}

If $t\neq 1$ the three vectors are linealy independent.

I want to extend these to a basis:

- $t\neq 1$ :

  We need one more vector. We write the given vectors as lines of a matrix and write one zero line:

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 
1& 
-1 & 
t
\\ t& 2& 0& 1 \\ 2& 
2& 
2& 
0\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$

We have to write in a row-echelon form, so we get the following, or not? 
$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 
2& 
2 & 0
\\ 0& 1& -1&t \\ 0 &
0& 
4-4t& 
2t^2-4t+2\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$

At the diagonal we write $1$: 
\begin{equation*}\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 
2& 
2 & 0
\\ 0& 1& -1&t \\ 0 &
0& 
4-4t& 
2t^2-4t+2\\ 0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\end{equation*}

Which is now the basis? The three initial vectors and the last line of that matrix? Or all the lines of the matrix?

Comment: The matrix with a zero row clearly cannot be full rank, so how can its columns or rows form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: Isn't that the method to extend a set to a basis? @K.Miller

Comment: Pick any vector not in the span of your given three vectors. Nearly *every* vector has that property; all you have to do is to pick something and check that it's independent. The only 'trick' is to avoid falling into some sort of psychological trap that prevents you from picking something outside of the span. (e.g. for a problem like this, you might need your chosen vector to involve $t$ rather than have four constants)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the fact that
$$
\mathbb{R}^4=C(A)\oplus N(A^T)
$$
so you just need to find a basis of the null space of $A^T$.

\begin{align}
A^T=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & -1 & t \\
t & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
t & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & t 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\leftrightarrow R_1, R_1\gets\frac{1}{2}R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 2-t & -t & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & t 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_2\gets R_2-R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & t \\
0 & 2-t & -t & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\leftrightarrow R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & t \\
0 & 0 & 2-2t & t^2-2t+1
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_3\gets R_3+(2-t)R_2
\end{align}
If $t=1$, the matrix is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad R_1\gets R_1-R_2
$$
so a basis for $N(A^T)$ is given by
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 \\ 1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
by solving the system $A^T=0$ and isolating two linearly independent solutions.

For $t\ne1$ you can go further in the elimination. I leave to you ending it.

Comment: So, is what I have done for $t\neq 1$ not correct?

Comment: @MaryStar Adding a zero line is meaningless.

Comment: I found that methodology here: http://massmatics.de/merkzettel/#!354:Vektoren_zu_Basis_ergaenzen

Comment: @MaryStar Sorry, I don't read German. The method I outlined works in every case.

Comment: Ah ok... But how can we go further at the elimination for $t\neq 1$ ? We already reached a row-echelon form.

Comment: @MaryStar You solve the system $A^Tx=0$, which has a non zero solution: such a vector is the one you need.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix

$$
A  =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & t & 2 & a\\
-1 & 0 & 2 & b\\
t & 1 & 0 & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Applying elementary row operations to $A$ you end up with

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 2 & 4 & b + 1\\
0 & 0 & 4-4t & 2a - t(b + 1)\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2a + 2c-b - 1+t(b-1)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So in order to have a basis you need to choose $a, b, c, t$ such that $t\neq 1$ and $2a + 2c-b - 1+t(b-1) \neq 0$. For an even simpler approach observe that appending the vector $(0,0,0,1)$ as the fourth column of $A$ results in a full rank matrix if $t\neq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can compute the vector that is perpendicular to the other three vectors by computing the generalized cross product of the first three colums:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0&t&2&4-4t\\
1&2&2&2t^2-2\\
-1&0&2&-2(t-1)^2\\
t&1&0&4-4t
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Each element in the fourth column is the [cofactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) at that position.

In addition, the determinant of the matrix is
$$
\left(4-4t\right)^2+\left(2t^2-2\right)^2+\left(2(t-1)^2\right)^2+\left(4-4t\right)^2
$$
Since the only common factor of the terms is $1-t$, the determinant is $0$ only when $t=1$.